# responsive html overlay on top of page with close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create responsive html overlay (which contains one image and close button).  It should be from 30px down from top of page.

I tried below code:

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlaymain">
        <img class="overlayimage" src="http://assets.cobaltnitra.com/teams/repository/export/v/1/391/435a06bcb100589f410145edef087/391435a06bcb100589f410145edef087.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    opacity:0.9;
}
.overlaymain {
    top:30px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0kp6k0x/1/)**

I am unable to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following - it uses css3 to keep the overlay image centred (use full page link on snippet below and resize browser to test) and should work in all major browsers.

I wasn't sure what the wrapper div was for so I have removed it.  You can add it back if you want as it doesn't make any difference to the code below.

```js
var overlay = $('.overlay'),
    close = $('<div class="close">close</div>');

overlay.append(close);

$(overlay, close).on('click', function () {
    overlay.fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:30px;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7); /* use this so that the image doesn't go opaque too */
}
.overlay > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* center the image in the overlay */
}
.close {
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000000;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
watsapppwatsapppwatsappp
<br>
<br>watsapppwatsapppwatsappp
<div class="overlay">
    <img class="overlayimage" src="http://assets.cobaltnitra.com/teams/repository/export/v/1/391/435a06bcb100589f410145edef087/391435a06bcb100589f410145edef087.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, You're trying to make a popup window. 
The easiest way is to use some nice jQuery plugin like [THIS](http://justcapelle.com/css3-slick-modal-popups/)

But if you want to do it yourself, you have to set wrapper's position to fixed and put that div on top in DOM.

You can make close button with jQuery like this:

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    $(".wrapper").hide();
});
```

Here's your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0kp6k0x/6/) with close button

Answer (score 0):

make changes in wrapper css

```
    .wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        background:red;
        opacity:0.5;
        top:30px;
    }
    .overlaymain {
        position:absolute;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0kp6k0x/4/)

Comment: what about close button ?

Answer (score 0):

Um, you didn't put your content inside the wrapper. I'm assuming the wrapper is your regular content and overlaymain is your overlay..

http://jsfiddle.net/u0kp6k0x/5/

```
<div class="wrapper">watsapppwatsapppwatsappp
    <br />
    <br />watsapppwatsapppwatsappp
    <div class="overlaymain">
        <img class="overlayimage" src="http://assets.cobaltnitra.com/teams/repository/export/v/1/391/435a06bcb100589f410145edef087/391435a06bcb100589f410145edef087.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't put in any attempt of code for one. Make some effort if you expect people to make some for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS and it should work:

```
.wrapper {
background:red;
    opacity:0.9;
    position:absolute; /*needed*/
    display: block; /*needed*/
    height:350px; /*choose desired height*/
    width: 550px; /*choose desired width*/
    top: 30px; /*distance to page-top*/
    left: 0; /*needed*/
    right: 0; /*needed*/
    margin: auto; /*this centers the div horizontally*/

}

.overlaymain {} /*this is not needed for the overlay*/
```